# Comparing ways of updating data (state) from lifting state up, should or should not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to do update data (state) from another file (function) (lifting state up). According to my research there are many ways to do so.

The below are some methods, I could think of.

However, I really dont know which one is the best.

```
function ListOFOrders() {
    const [ listOrders, setListOrders ] = useState([])

    //Method 1
    const addingOrders = (data) => {
        let temp_list = listOrders
        temp_list.push(data)
        setListOrders(temp_a)
    }

    //Method 2 
    const addingOrders = (data) => {
        setListOrders([...listOrders, data])
    }

    //Method 3
    const addingOrders = (data) => {
        setListOrders(prevListOrders => [...prevListOrders, {...data}])
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <OrdersForm addingOrders ={addingOrders}/>
        <OrdersList orders={listOrders}/>  
    </div>
        )
    }
```

The `method 1` is from pure `JavaScript`. It is not working since the page is not re-render again to update new data to the screen. I did `console.log` at the end of function to check and data is indeed, added (updated). I really dont know why. Please help

The `method 2` and `method 3` are working. But `method 2` has to call `listOrders` of the current state while the other does not to. Which one should I use ?

For your information, `data` of `addingOrders` could be like this

```
{
    id : 1
    title : 'a_title'
}
```

Comment: If in version 1 you meant `setListOrders(temp_list)` the reason this doesn't work is two-fold, (1) you mutated the previous state and then (2) you didn't provide a *new* state array reference, so because React uses shallow reference equality and the reference didn't change it will bail on rerendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 should not be used (and often won't work) because state should never be mutated in React. `.push` mutates the existing array in state.

Method 2 is *usually* fine, but there are occasionally instances when it could be problematic if the `listOrders` array it closes over is in a stale closure - for example, if `addingOrders` gets called after an API call, and the state may have changed in the meantime. In such a situation, you might lose items you previously added to `listOrders` in between when the API call was initialized and when it finished.

The solution to the stale closure problem is method 3: use the callback form, whose first argument will be the current stateful value.

If you're sure `addingOrders` won't be called asynchronously, then method 2 is just fine - method 3 is unnecessary.

I see you do `{...data}` in method 3 as well. This will be useful if `data` may be mutated elsewhere - creating a shallow copy of it can reduce the chance of external mutation causing problems.